# How to save the user input data from a dialog box into a hidden field: Jquery and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on this button that opens a dialog box containing an option-selecting table when clicked on. The thing is, I want the data input by the customer to be saved in a hidden field.

I have tried targeting the speicific field with getElementById, but I have no idea how to check whether or not it worked.

```
$(function() {
   $("#opener").click(function() {
        ($("#table").dialog("isOpen") == false) ? $("#table").dialog("open") : $("#table").dialog("close") ;
        });
        $("#table").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 250,
            position: ['center',100],
            buttons: {
                Abbrechen: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }, 

                Fertig: function() {
                    $('input[name="hfield"').val($("#safety_gear_select").val());
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }

           },
        });
```

Does anyone know how can I achieve this? TIA

Comment: Abbrechen means cancel and fertig means done, so pretty much the cancel button should not submit anything, whereas the Fertig button should be the one holding the onclick event where the inputs are being saved in a hidden field. Does it make any sense? I feel like this is a dumb question haha

Comment: I used console.log too, I seem to have figured it out! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, hopefully it will help someone else too. 
This is what I added to my button's code, where 'hfield1' is the name of the hidden field I want the data saved in and the #safety_gear_select is the id of the select field containing the input I wanna save in the hidden field. 
It displays the name of the choice in the console rather than the index number, but that can easily be achieved too by replacing .html() with .val()

`Fertig: function() {
                        $('input[name="hfield1"').val($("#safety_gear_select option:selected").html());
                        $('input[name="hfield2"').val($("#pawl_device_select option:selected").html() );
                        $('input[name="hfield3"').val($("#buffer_select option:selected").html() );
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }`